# Error: no results matched the query

Tags: ios, parse-platform

method in one class:

```
- (IBAction)createGroup:(id)sender {
    PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
    [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDate" sender:self];
    }];
}
```

then in another:

```
    else {
            PFQuery *message = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Message"];
                [message getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"message" block:^(PFObject *message,         NSError *error) {
                [message setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
                [message setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];
                [message setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] username] forKey:@"senderName"];
                [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

When I run the app, there are no errors or warnings but it terminates throwing the error when the query is accessed. I'm sure it is something simple that I am overlooking as I just popped my programming cherry a week ago. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: It's definitely something with your parse configuration. You should probably check their support pages / FAQ / forums first.

Comment: Been looking for the last 4 hours and tried everything I can think of. Feeling a bit discouraged. thanks though

Comment: You might get somebody here who knows parse, I added the tag so who knows. Are you able to get the basic "getting-started" type parse code working? My guess is that it's some configuration setting somewhere.

Comment: I had set up a segue for the IBButton before I set up the action for it to create the Parse file. Is it possible that it is performing the segue FIRST, before the program has a chance to create the PFObject?

Comment: yes, I was able to upload data to Parse just last night. I have a user base and was able to create columns and rows using the keys. This morning, however, I needed to split the PFObject between two controllers and now things are all screwy.

Comment: Anything's possible. Definitely use breakpoints to check the timing of your object creation. Unfortunately I have almost no experience with parse, so other than that, I can't be of much help :( There's nothing egregiously or obviously wrong with the code snippets you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` expects a Parse object ID for the `objectId` parameter.

If you're simply creating the object and then trying to pass it through to a child view controller, it might be better to pass through the actual `PFObject`.

```
//In your header
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *message;

 //Implementation
 (IBAction)createGroup:(id)sender {
   PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
   [message setObject:self.recipients forKey:@"recipientIds"];
   [message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
           NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       }
       else {
         self.message = message;
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDate" sender:self];
       }
   }];
}
```

You'll need to implement `prepareForSeque:sender:` in your view controller, and then pass the PFObject through to the child view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDate"]) {
    YourChildViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.message = self.message;
  }
}
```

Then in your child view controller:

```
//In the header, create a property to hold the message object
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *message;

//In the body, you can use self.message
  [self.message setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
  [self.message setObject:fileType forKey:@"fileType"];
  [self.message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  ...
```

Comment: ok, I'm getting an "expected expression" warning on the line for the "else" statement. should self.objectId be moved down to be included in the else statement?

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're right - that should be in the else block. You'll also need to add a property to your class to hold the object ID (to allow you do to `self.objectId`. I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Now the app is terminating at the same spot and I am getting this thrown 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)' I guess I'm not really understanding.

Comment: Do I need to set the property in both header files? or just import the one that it is declared in? also, does the property need to be set to 'retain' or is 'strong' what I need as you have? sorry to ask so many questions hah. I've just been stuck on this one issue all day and would like nothing more than to move past it. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. I didn't entirely understand the question before. I've updated my answer - hopefully it's more helpful this time. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: do I still need to query parse to access the object? or is that what self.message is doing? cause now when I run it, I get no errors or warnings but the app just freezes at the point where the errors were previously being called. I checked on parse to see if the 'message' class was even created, and it had not been. ::feeling a bit conquered::

Comment: Hmm, I'd try putting breakpoints throughout your code (in `createGroup:`, `prepareForSegue`, etc), and checking the value and properties of `self.message` at each point. Particularly check that the `message` property is populated in your child view controller. You shouldn't need the query in your child view controller any more, because you're passing the object itself.

Comment: It shouldn't do. The block in `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` shouldn't be executed until the object has been saved to Parse. I'm not sure what's going on in your case. It might be worth experimenting with saving data to Parse from a single view controller (without performing the segue), to see if that behaves differently.

Comment: I had it saving images to Parse last night from a single view controller. But this morning I needed to divide the recipients up so that they could be selected on a screen prior to the data being uploaded with the UIImagePicker. Now it's all messed up though :/